# File open dialog application stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have written code for file dialog in android and it was working perfect but today when i run code then my application crashes unexpectedly.  I have written file dialog application which shows all paths in ListView.

My full activity code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;
    private TextView myPath;
            static private String pos;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View v= findViewById(R.id.rowtext);


        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);



    }

    public void bt_Quit(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }

    public  void back(View v)
    {
        getDir(pos);

    }
    public  void home(View v)
    {
        getDir(root);

    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {


        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
               pos=f.getParent();
        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
        {

        }


        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }else{
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }   
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead()){
                getDir(path.get(position));

            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();  
            }   
        }else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

          }
    }

}
```

**MY logcat-output is:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1584)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1264)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:845)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
    .
```

Comment: can you show the line where you get that classCastException in your code?

Comment: my full application code is as follows?

Comment: check my edit question now it includes code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
```

You need to provide not a layout resource, but a TextView resource, [for example](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
```

Comment: I have changed it but still my application is crashing

Comment: is it the same crash that was before?

Comment: no sir app was not crashing before it just crashing tonight i dont know i even havent touch the app code

Comment: I mean does logcat changed after you try my piece of code or you still get your first exception?

Comment: no logcat is changed now now i am getting nullpointer exception

Comment: for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)

Comment: and in this line getDir(root);

Comment: So your files variable is null. Actually, I solved your question. I think, that you can handle NullPointerException by yourself. I won't debug your code for you

Comment: sir root variable is not null i have checked it but it is not going into getdir function